# Attribute routing not working MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is a long post. I am using attribute routing as described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#enabling-attribute-routing

I have placed in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
         {
             config.EnableCors();
+            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
}
```

in Global.asax.cs

```
             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
+            //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
+            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
             FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

and I am using a webapi controller with:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
    {
[Route("Services/test/Application/{id}")]
        public string GetTest(int id)
        {
    return "1";
    }
}
```

I am using Postman Chrome extension to test. On my own computer when I test in Visual Studio this is working perfectly: http://localhost:6296/Services/test/Application/12
and returns the expected result, but after I deploy it on a site, it does not work: http://www.mytest.com/Services/test/Application/12 (tested even on the server localhost: http://localhost/Services/test/Application/12)
and returns:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Services/test/Application/12
```

The reference System.Web.Mvc (version 5.2.3.0) is marked as "copy local = true". No authorization is used. Classic webapi controlls work perfectly on the server and locally.

Question: what could be wrong and where should I start looking?!

Comment: Could be your HelloController isn't making it to the website. Also if this is really your code "as-is" then it won't compile. The return value of GetTest() is a string but you are returning the integer 1. - Or maybe this is one of those new auto-cast C# improvements.

Comment: My error. Corrected. How should I check that the controller is making it to the site?

Comment: All depends on how your web site is hosted. If it is your Server or something you have remote access to (Remote Desktop, VNC...), then you just go look in the file system. Say you were publishing to Azure, you could look a the publish log or output window to make sure the file was copied - but make a change first so it knows it need to update it.

Comment: @Mike Actually I can remote allright to the published site and the error is even when I try there on localhost. The controller I think is not a folder or file to look for, it is inside a dll so it is rather hard to look into.  I have removed all dlls, re-published, same error. I think the error would rather be related to software/dlls missing on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Comment: I added it after and is not working. Strange that attribute routing is working in Visual studio localhost without this too:                        config.EnableCors();
   ++         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: I have mine setup with just routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); maybe it the same as MapHttpAttributesRoutes, I didn't see it in your setup that's why I suggested adding it.

Comment: Yes I have seen the tutorial suggests adding that and mine is working without it in VS localhost. Added it anyway now but the same answer on the server:The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry confusion with MapHttpAttributeRoutes in the previous answer. Added MapMvcAttributeRoutes to RouteConfig and the same:        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );}